# Looking for a Form Validation Test

Tags: forms, validation

I am trying to find a way to test and verify my form validation is doing all it can to protect me from script injections. Is there a tool that I can use to test and verify my forms for any known vulnerabilities.

Comment: After a bit more research. It looks like the name of the tool I was looking for is a Form Fuzzer. This tool attempts to break Form Validation. It probably best to do this in a Sandbox because the results can be intrusive and possible destroy your database. This is all new to me, so dont take my word for it do some research and hopefully I can get some good feebback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed this question was never answered well enough for me to except an answer. I ended up using a form fuzzer. A browser add on like this https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/immuniweb-self-fuzzer/ will enter data into the form inputs and try to break your form validation inputing various kinds of data. Best to work on a development/sandbox type environment since the data input an potentially destroy your database.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Webdevelopment?
You should prevalidate your forms using javascript or jquery logic. But this will not bring you any security, it will just reduce server traffic, because non valid forms will not be send to the server doing so.

Further more you have to validate your forms at the server using php or what ever you use on server side. 
Do not forget to use htmlspecialchars whenever you display variable input values to be aware of xss attacks. 
Use mysqlrealescapestring or some escaping for the dbs you are using. If you use an orm escaping is mostly done automaticly.

you asked for a tool? you can use the zend framework, it is complicated but it has some form validation automatisms. 
E.g: you can validate ISBN numbers, email addresses or bar codes with it automatically.

Comment: I am referring to web development. Im using Wordpress with Buddypress and I have looked into its validation a little bit. Im looking at each input field and seeing how it is validating each but how do I know for certain that there isnt some weakness in the validation. The tool I was looking for was a tool to forcefully check and ensure my forms do proper validation for known vulnerabilities. In other words try to exploit the weaknesses of my forms.

Comment: Here is a link to the type of tools I was looking for. http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html#SECURITY Does anyone have any feedback on any of these tools or something better?

Comment: After a bit more research. It looks like the name of the tool I was looking for is a Form Fuzzer. This tool attempts to break Form Validation. It probably best to do this in a Sandbox because the results can be intrusive and possible destroy your database. This is all new to me, so dont take my word for it do some research and hopefully I can get some good feebback.